# Creating a ComboBox with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to all this, and I am having no luck in finding the answers anywhere.
I am trying to create a combobox with PDO but I am just unable to get it to work correctly. My results show the array and everything in the array.

What I want to show is in one combobox the equipment_model and if possible based on that selection a field to the right of it with the price that is associated with that model.

If more information is required let me know. Again I am new to this and want to learn.

```
 <form>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Selecting elements</legend>
      <p>
         <label>Furnace</label>
     <select name="Equipment1" id = "Equipment1"> 
 <option id="1">
 <?PHP
require_once 'php/func_inc.php';
$odb=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proposal_site', 'root', '');
$query = "select equipment_model from equipment_master";
    $data = $odb->prepare($query);    // Prepare query for execution
    $data->execute();// Execute (run) the query



    $row=$data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    print_r($row); 
    ?>
 </option>





     </select>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is echo out the option as you fetching each row.

I suggest you to add the `equipment_id` in your query:

```
select equipment_id, equipment_model from equipment_master
```

and print it in the loop:

```
<select name="Equipment1" id = "Equipment1"> 
<?php
require_once 'php/func_inc.php';
$odb=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proposal_site', 'root', '');
$query = "select equipment_id, equipment_model from equipment_master";
    $data = $odb->prepare($query);    // Prepare query for execution
    $data->execute();// Execute (run) the query

    while($row=$data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['equipment_id'].'">'.$row['equipment_model'].'</option>';
        //print_r($row); 
    }
?>
 </select>
```

This will build the select with the options.

A better approach would be to populate it using ajax since you have the intention to manipulate the select tag.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I will study this and try to understand it. I do have another thing I wanted to do with this, but didn't want to ask until I understood how to get the results I wanted. I wanted to create a field right next to it to get the price of that model. Is that something I do in the while statement or elsewhere?

Comment: Where is the price in the same table?

Comment: Yes. Same table under billed_amount. I tried playing around with it as echo '<input value="'.$row['billed_amount'].'">'.$row['billed_amount'].'</option>'; but I got all the equipment models and price on the same line.

Comment: its option not input `echo '<option value="'.$row['billed_amount'].'">'.$row['billed_amount'].'</option>';` you will need to use something like jquery to show the selected value in the input

Answer (score -4):

It should be a good start point for you

```
...
<?PHP
require_once 'php/func_inc.php';
$odb=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proposal_site', 'root', '');
$query = "select equipment_model from equipment_master";
$data = $odb->prepare($query);    // Prepare query for execution
$data->execute();// Execute (run) the query

while ($row = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    echo  '<option value="'.$row['equipment_model'].'">'.$row['equipment_model'].'</option>';
}
...
```

You should consider using PHP frameworks

Comment: If the $query is ok - what's wrong with that fetchAll?

Comment: There will be no `id` index.

Comment: Did you mean object instead of array? It's hard to understand your second comment about fetchAll..

Comment: This is not going to work. You are specifying PDO::FETCH_ASSOC to fetch an associative array but then accessing the array like an object.

Comment: This is only "good start point". I'm not going to implement a fully working solution because I don't have enough information. 
I think it's better than print_r

Comment: I just want to return all values from the one column "Equipment_model" into the combobox like a dropdown. I thought returning it as an array would give me access to all these values. Again I am very noob and just started learning this last night. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Yes I have. I have received this message in the option result. (!) Notice: Undefined index: equipment_model in c:\wamp\www\...

Comment: The old way I had it written out I could see the Array[] and all the columns with their value but couldn't get the one columns values.

Comment: add var_dump($row) into while and see what's the problem

Comment: I received the same (!)Notice: Undefined index: equipment_model as before.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz for your help. I was able to learn more about this with your assistance.